# Easy and cheap replacement options for GU10 lighting

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I've got a bunch of GU10 spots in my basement ceiling, and while they do a good job keeping the place well lit, the narrow beam of the bulb along with the low ceiling create a bunch of light spots. That wouldn't be an issue but my dog goes crazy about these spots and tries to dig right under, so now I have to replace the floor linoleum in the whole basement.

So basically I'm looking for options that would let me replace the GU10 bulbs with something that disperses the light, so the dog stays calm and the new floor remains intact.

I have so far found a couple of wide angle GU10 options on Amazon, but they are of really bad quality, nothing like the normal brand name LEDs.

Any suggestions are welcome
Thanks

Comment: They do *sell* [GU10-to-E26 adapters](https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-JACKYLED-Pin-Bayonet-Converter-Resistant/dp/B00CETCISM) on Amazon, but I can't vouch for their safety.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wide variety of GU10 bulbs available. Not quite as many as standard Edison base bulbs, but still quite a few. For example, just doing a very quick search on Home Depot, I found bulbs from 88 to 600 lumens (one said 20 lumens, but I think that was an incorrectly entered data point for a "20 watt equivalent" bulb), various color temperatures, CRI, etc. Go to a specialty company such as 1000bulbs.com and you'll find even more.

That being said, the best option may be to replace the actual fixtures, as GU10 bulbs all seem to have the same basic shape. Because LED lights can be very thin (no need for a "bulb" except nostalgia and compatibility with existing fixtures), surface mount lights are often an option even with low ceilings. Or recessed cans. Or almost anything.

Starting point is *not*: Watts, "Watts equivalent" or physical size. It should always be *how much light* = **lumens**. Figure out how much light you currently get based on the bulbs in use. Then figure out if you want more, less or about the same total light in the room. And then you can figure out what to get. You can also consider getting *more* light than you currently have but using a dimmer to adjust as needed.

Don't be too scared about "fixtures with built-in LEDs" not letting you replace bulbs. If you pick decent quality fixtures they should last several years. Just make sure you get enough light, high CRI and a color temperature that you like.

Comment: DV care to explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: But... but... I've bought bulbs based on watts for _years_! You can't expect me to change now...

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find LEDs with good CRI, the right color temperature (3000K), nice tint, etc... and they're not available with diffused lens. Widest available is 60°.

Most LED GU10 have plastic optics. Some optics are barely glued and can be persuaded to come off, especially on [OSRAM](https://www.lampesdirect.fr/osram-parathom-led-gu10-spot-claire-4-5w-350lm-930-blanc-chaud-dimmable-meilleur-rendu-des-couleurs-equivalent-50w-4058075797963), which by coincidence is the cheapest GU10 with good color.

Without changing the fixtures, here's a zero cost solution:

If you want to make a diffused GU10 from a tight beam one, just sandblast the front of the optics. Steel wool or sandpaper also works, or a steel brush.

Removing the lens makes a floodlight. It can also be replaced with a piece of plastic diffuser.

The printed circuit board inside may be at mains voltage, so watch out.

Comment: Cool idea, I'll try with one, see how it goes

Comment: a small circle tissue paper diffuser attached with a gluestick will turn it into a soft (shadowless) source. You can also remove the "lens" altogether on many of them, just pry it off with a butter knife; the LED chips themselves typically cast a 160deg beam.

Comment: Yes I've popped the lens on some of mine, to make floodlights instead of spots. Works great but only in light fixtures where you won't be looking directly at the LEDs though. LED printed circuit board may be at mains voltage, so watch out.

Comment: I can't imagine that glue stick glue would hold up well to the heat of a light bulb, @dandavis. Not even an LED (which doesn't make much heat itself, but the driver electronics sure do).

Comment: Applying acetone to some clear plastics will fog them and give a matte aspect. It doesn't work with all plastics. It evaporates, so once it's gone there's no risk.

Comment: @FreeMan the lenses don't actually get very hot, even when the metal body is scalding. Note that I don't mean hot melt glue sticks (though even with those, hi-temp should suffice), buy rather the kindergarten variety of twist-ups.

Comment: Kindergarten style is what I was thinking... Maybe I'm just not familiar enough with GU10 bulbs to know what you're referring to, so I'll just quietly back away...

Comment: What about something like baking parchment? Heat resistant enough and should work as well as tissue paper, no?